# Unable to acces Power Designer web portal

Tags: web, portal, powerdesigner

I'm trying to access the Power Designer portal from a browser; something like this:

> https://powerdesigner-web/resources/index.html

But the page is not loading, and this is the message displayed:

> This page can’t be displayed.

Do you have any suggestions?

It could be something related to SSL. If yes, how can enable this? I need to mention that I already tried to enabled SSL, but I don't know if I succeed.

Thanks, 
Madalin

Comment: The URL seems a little short, missing server and port. Maybe something like this `https://localhost:3030/powerdesigner-web/resources/index.html` , or something else that localhost depending on where your server is installed. If you suspect https, you can replace it with http...  Do you have any more information in the browser console?...

Comment: My bad; i removed the server name. So the link is like that
https://aaa.bbb.ccc.dd/powerdesigner-web/resources/index.html

Comment: Some more information in the browser console? I'm still unclear whether this is a problem with a missing port indication (3030 for the server by default?), or an actual problem with the behavior of the NodeJS / Tomcat services...

Comment: Meanwhile i've managet to install the certificates. https://<my_server>:8443 is working. But when i try to acces the full path https://<my_serve>:8443/powerdesigner-web/resources/index.html is not working. From logs i got this: [24/Jul/2019:12:48:40 +0300] "GET /powerdesigner-web/resources/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1047. Could be the path wrong?

Comment: 8443 looks like the port number to Tomcat. There is also a NodeJS service, and your browser should be talking to NodeJS, which will then serve from cache, or ask Tomcat to build the page.That's why I was mentioning port 3030. I'm not sure which doc you followed to SSL-enable your server... [Here is one](https://help.sap.com/viewer/1f914d86319d43b7b2402532666583c0/16.6.7/en-US/c80f1dc66e1b10149834b423c1b9caf0.html) which seems to cover all points.